# Error casting List.Select().Cast<myObj>() to myObj

Tags: c#, linq

Hi guys I have the following code:

```
var v = gridInList.Select(s => s.HeaderCellText == cmbScegliColonnaPopolazione.Text).Cast<myGrid.GridInList>();
            myGrid.GridInList 
tempClass =(myGrid.GridInList) v;
```

And when i run the program I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<CastIterator>d__b1`1[myGrid.GridInList]' to type 'myGrid.GridInList'.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `.Cast()` doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cast<T>` returns `IEnumerable<T>` not `T`. You might want to use `First` to get the first element in the enumerable.

Comment: @SJuan I assume you mean '.Single()'

Comment: Do `.First()` at the end of the command. Or `.FirstOrDefault()` if the `Select` may be empty.